# Spiral Matrix java

Tags: java, matrix, spiral

I tried to solve the problem, but it didn't work.
description:
implement its static method:

- `int[][] spiral(int rows, int columns)`
  Return a two-dimensional array coming in the form of a table and containing numbers from `1` up to `rows * columns`. The size of the table will be specified by the given parameters.
  Numbers fill the "table" clockwise from the top-level corner in a spiral manner.
  For example, for parameter values `(3, 4)`, the output array should be:

  ```
   1  2  3  4
  10 11 12  5
   9  8  7  6

  static int[][] spiral(int rows, int columns) {
     int mat[][] = new int[rows][columns];
      int counter = 1;
      int startCol = 0;
      int endCol = columns - 1;
      int startRows = 0;
      int endRows = rows -1;

      while (startRows <= endRows && startCol <= endCol){
          for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++){
              mat[startRows][i] = counter;
              counter++;
          }
          startRows++;

          for (int j = startRows; j <= endRows; j++){
              mat[j][endCol] = counter;
              counter++;
          }
          endCol--;

          for (int l = endCol; l >= startCol; l--){
              mat[endRows][l] = counter;
              counter++;
          }
          endRows--;

          for(int y = endRows; y >= startRows; y--){
              mat[y][startCol] = counter;
              counter++;
          }
          startCol++;
      }

      return mat;
  }
  ```

}

Expected :

> [[1;2;3;4;5;6];
> [18;19;20;21;22;7];
> [17;28;29;30;23;8];
> [16;27;26;25;24;9];
> [15;14;13;12;11;10]]

Actual   :

> [[1;2;3;4;5;6];
> [18;19;20;21;22;7];
> [17;28;31;30;23;8];
> [16;27;26;25;24;9];
> [15;14;13;12;11;10]]

Comment: You should use a debugger and step through your code. It appears your loop performs correct until the last line through the center. You probably write, 29 and 30 correctly, then overwrite 29 with 31.

Answer (score 0):

The *while* condition is valid for filling a number.
But before every *for* loop the condition must still hold.

```
while (startRows <= endRows && startCol <= endCol){
    for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++){
        mat[startRows][i] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
    startRows++;

    for (int j = startRows; j <= endRows; j++){
        mat[j][endCol] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
    endCol--;

    if (startRows > endRows) {
        break;
    }
    for (int l = endCol; l >= startCol; l--){
        mat[endRows][l] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
    endRows--;

    if (startCol > endCol) {
        break;
    }
    for(int y = endRows; y >= startRows; y--){
        mat[y][startCol] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
    startCol++;
}
```

I added two breaks on going back.

Otherwise the algorithm is quite elegant, and maybe you can find a way to clean up my hacky conditions.

I did not test the code.

You might have written tracing code to see the logic. A log statement after every `counter++;`.

Comment: It seems like they way they've setup their for loops they could eliminate the additional check. I suppose it has to do with the row condition changing, but the column iterations never checking if it is still in a valid row. Why not use your break conditions based on counter?

Comment: @matt checking on counter is easier but more magical, for guaranteeing that the indexing remains in the ever slinking rectangle. **Mind I would not be surprised if it is just the case that my answer is incorrect.**